# Ajax call to webmethod is giving errror "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Tags: asp.net-ajax

below is my code...
when i am checking error using developer tool bar its showing the following error as soon as my webmethod in .aspx page  is called using ajax:
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

***Javascript code:***

```
        $('#<%=txtUsername.ClientID%>').mouseout(function () {


            var userName = $("#<%=txtUsername.ClientID%>").val();


                $.ajax({
                    url: 'Signup.aspx/checkUsername',
                    method: 'post',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: "{username:'" + userName + "'}",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: (function (data)
                    {
                       alert(data);

                    })
                ,
                    error: (function (error) {

                        alert('error is:'+error);
                    })
                });
        });
```

***aspx method***

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public string checkUsername(string username)
    {
        string status;
        string CS = 
     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spCheckUsername", con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
            con.Open();

            status = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        }
        return status;

    }
```

Comment: please help me out ...as i am not able to put a breakpoint in my aspx webmethod

Answer (score 0):

Try making your method static:

```
public static string checkUsername(string username)...
```

Comment: Also, a better content type: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`.